# How to achieve vertical lift using magnets

Tags: electromagnetism

Is there a way to create vertical lift using magnets which are aligned with same facing polarity?

Comment: Could you be a bit more verbose?

Comment: I am guessing you mean if you had two magnets placed say,  north pole to north pole, could they repel each other to cause one to lift?